# Extending dimensions

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras, multidimensional-array, tensor

Loading data from tensorflow returns ndarry   `(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)` where the data is of shape `(num_samples, 3, 32, 32)` I want to extend this shape to include another dimension to have something of  `[num_classes, num_samples, im_height, im_width, im_channels].`

So for Cifar100, for instance, `x_train.shape` should be `(100,50000, 32, 32, 3)`.

I tried reshaping as in `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (100, len(x_train), 32,32,1))` but this doesnt work. Neither does adding a new axis solve the problem.

Comment: You may need a transpose if the size 3 dimension has to be moved to the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reshape because the total number of elements is different.

You need to create a new array and copy the data in whatever pattern you need.  For example:

```
new_x_train = np.empty((100, 50000, 32, 32, 3), x_train.dtype)
new_x_train[:] = x_train # 100 copies of x_train using broadcasting
```

Or, equivalently:

```
new_x_train = np.broadcast_to(x_train, (100, 50000, 32, 32, 3))
```

Comment: Yes! I totally forgot about `broadcast_to`. Thanks that solved it. Marking as answer. Thanks